# ubuntu version of pip installs package_data to purelib

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, python-wheel

I am trying to understand why a wheel created by Python 3.10 on `Ubuntu 22.04` is placing my `package_data` into a `purelib` directory while `Anaconda` (python 3.12) and `manylinux2014` (python 3.11 is not).

My `setup.py`:

```
from setuptools import setup, dist
import os
import re

class BinaryDistribution(dist.Distribution):
    """Distribution which always forces a binary package with platform name"""
    def has_ext_modules(self):
        return True

setup(
        packages=['pyfoo',],
        package_data={
            'pyfoo' : ['./fooJSON', './fooJSON.exe'],
        },
        distclass=BinaryDistribution,
    )
```

where `fooJSON` is a binary executable.  After running:

```
pip wheel .
```

On `Anaconda` and `Manylinux 2_28` python it gets placed in the wheel as:

```
pyfoo/fooJSON
```

where on Ubuntu it is placed as:

```
pyfoo-0.0.2.data/purelib/pyfoo/fooJSON
```

What is the proper way to indicate package_data is not purelib?  Is Ubuntu an outlier?

Anaconda: pip 23.3.1
Ubuntu 22.04: pip 22.0.2

Comment: What does the wheel contain? (`zipinfo *.whl`)

Comment: The paths above are from "unzip -t"